# Get the indexes of javascript array elements that satisfy condition - nearest elements sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Is there a way to use reduce method to get a indexes of 2 nearest array elements that satisfy condition (sum of these elements).

This is my solution, but I believe there should be more elegant and short solution.
Any suggestions?

```
function indexes(sum, data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i] + data[i+1] === sum) {
      return [i, i+1]
    } 
  } return 'no match'
}
```

Comment: The current approach does not use `reduce`?

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense: https://jsfiddle.net/fh9uv830/ I believe your `for` loop is more clear and readable.

Comment: Using `.reduce()` wouldn't give you any advantage nor would it look elegant and short.

Comment: check what will happen in these cases: `indexes(4,[1,2,3,4])` ; `indexes(0,[3,2,1,0])`